# Joomla 4 Custom Component > Custom Fields Integration

Tags: joomla-4.x, custom-component, custom-field

I'm curently developing a (free) Custom Joomla 4.x component. Now im struggeling while implementing Custom Fields support for my first (and currently only) context. The issue is that the "Fields" tab does not get showed in the backend when editing a "location". I've followed the guide by astrid on how to create a component.

It's the third time I create a component for joomla 4 and as far as i can see i've done everything similar to the others i've already created. I did not spot the issue here.

Could please someone check my repo here: [GitHub](https://github.com/marcorensch/com_footballmanager_2) and tell me what i am doing wrong?

thanks for your help

**Edit**

I've added the mentioned changes (thanks for that) and updated the repo, still no effect on the edit view for a location...

```
class FootballmanagerComponent extends MVCComponent implements FieldsServiceInterface

...

public function validateSection($section, $item = null)
    {
        if (Factory::getApplication()->isClient('site') && $section === 'form')
        {
            return 'footballmanager';
        }

        if ($section !== 'footballmanager' && $section !== 'form')
        {
            return null;
        }

        return $section;
    }

    public function getContexts(): array
    {
        Factory::getApplication()->getLanguage()->load('com_footballmanager', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR);

        $contexts = array(
            'com_footballmanager.location' => Text::_('COM_FOOTBALLMANAGER_LOCATION'),
//          'com_helloworld.categories' => JText::_('JCATEGORY')
        );

        return $contexts;
    }
```

What I see when i add fields for this component there is no "category" input in the fields that looks a bit suspicious to me.

Comment: Fix your model's `preprocessForm()` method so it always calls the parent method.

Comment: OMG - that was a dumb mistake - thanks @Sharky - can you create an answer so I can mark it as solution?

Answer (score 2):

At first glance you're missing the `getContexts` and `validateSection` methods which you should have in your extension class. Your extension class also needs to implement `Joomla\CMS\Fields\FieldsServiceInterface`.

The Joomla 3 MVC Tutorial description of how to include custom fields is at https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_Custom_Fields and the changes from this to Joomla 4 are described at https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Upgrading_to_Joomla4#com_fields.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - i've done the mentioned changes (but please note as i said the other components this where also missing and it workied (some kinda).. Updated my repo - still want work